# Fetch Android files using FTP and Python

Tags: android, python, ftp, connection, fetch

I'm currently struggling with some difficulties to fetch android files using a FTP server and Python. I installed on my Android device a application to act as an FTP server. I tested on the Windows explorer and was able to view and interact with the ftp data.

Now, I'm trying to create a simple Python script to extract the data of my device. So far I have the following line:

```
from ftplib import *

ftp = FTP('123.456.7.89:13000', 'username', 'password')
```

When I try to connect using this host I receive the following error message:

```
[Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

If I change the code to

```
ftp = FTP('123.456.7.89, 'username', 'password')
```

I receive the following message

```
 [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I was also able to list the files of a know test ftp 'ftp.microsoft.com' so probably the issue is in someway specific the way I'm trying to declare my host?

Comment: Your authentication parameters are a problem. Double check if you are using them correctly!

Comment: @Boggartly I double checked the parameters. I can't understand what you're referring as a problem.

Comment: If a host actively refuses a connection attempt, it means there is a problem with the  username and password scheme. Check it again. :D

Comment: Your port number can also be a problem. Ftp usually exits on port 21. Sftp on port 22.

Comment: @boggartly The port that I'm using is the one I define in the Android application that I have installed. I can't define either 21 or 22 as it requires an integer higher than 1023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ftp = FTP('123.456.7.89:13000', 'username', 'password')

The documentation of ftplib suggests that the first argument must be a host, not `host:port`. This explains also the following error:

> [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

This is an error from the resolver, because it tried to interpret the given name `123.456.7.89:13000` as hostname, IPv4 (or IPv6) and none of this worked.

If you use a non-standard port you have to do connect and login after you have created the FTP object, because there is no way to give a non-standard port to the object constructor:

```
 ftp = FTP()
 ftp.connect('123.456.7.89',13000)
 ftp.login(username,password)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and brilliant explanation. It worked out and I did understand my mistake. Cheers!